# alpine linux apache2 /var/www/modules/apr_dbd_mysql.so: my_init: symbol not found

Tags: php, mysql, docker, apache2, alpine-linux

I am using docker to build an image for my PHP website. The base image is `phpswoole/swoole:4.8-php7.3-alpine`. (alpine 3.13)

Here is the dockerfile commands for installing apache2 and dependencies.

```
apk add --no-cache apache2 php7-apache2 apr-util-dbd_mysql apache2-http2 apache2-proxy apache2-ssl apache2-utils
```

Then when I want to start apache2, I got the following error.

```
 * apache2 has detected an error in your setup:
httpd: Syntax error on line 169 of /etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/apr_dbd_mysql.so into server: Error relocating /var/www/modules/apr_dbd_mysql.so: my_init: symbol not found
 * ERROR: apache2 failed to start
```

When I used ubuntu, I could install `libaprutil1-dbd-mysql` to make `apr_dbd_mysql.so`. But in alpine 3.13, `apr-util-dbd_mysql` is the only package I could find. And by the way, because mysql server is installed in another docker container, in this docker image, there is no mysql server installed.

So how to get this apache issue solved? Is there any way that I can make `my_init` available, or is there a patch for `apr-util-dbd_mysql` package for alpine 3.13?

Any idea is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Update**

Dockerfile

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:experimental
FROM phpswoole/swoole:4.8-php7.3-alpine AS base


# Add repos
#RUN echo "https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.15/main" >> /etc/apk/repositories
#RUN echo "https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.15/cummunity" >> /etc/apk/repositories


# Inatall apahce & nginx (nginx is used as live stream server)
RUN set -ex \
    && apk update && apk upgrade \
    && apk add --no-cache openrc git \
    && apk add --no-cache $PHPIZE_DEPS bzip2-dev gettext-dev icu-dev gettext-dev gmp-dev libxslt-dev libxml2-dev freetype-dev libpng-dev libjpeg-turbo-dev libgcrypt-dev libsodium-dev musl-dev libzip-dev libexif-dev tidyhtml-dev pcre-dev openssl apr-dev apr-util-dev build-base \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr --with-png-dir=/usr --with-jpeg-dir=/usr \
    && docker-php-ext-install bcmath bz2 calendar exif gd gettext gmp intl mysqli pcntl shmop soap sysvmsg sysvsem sysvshm tidy xmlrpc xsl zip opcache \
    && docker-php-ext-enable bcmath bz2 calendar exif gd gettext gmp intl mysqli pcntl shmop soap sysvmsg sysvsem sysvshm tidy xmlrpc xsl zip opcache \
    && apk add --no-cache apache2 php7-apache2 apr-util-dbd_mysql apache2-http2 apache2-proxy apache2-ssl apache2-utils \
    # enable apache modules
    && ln -s /usr/lib/apr-util-1/apr_dbd_mysql.so /usr/lib/apache2/apr_dbd_mysql.so \
    && sed -i 's@^LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation\.so@LoadModule apr_dbd_mysql modules/apr_dbd_mysql.so@' /etc/apache2/httpd.conf \
    (ignore other apache2 modules)

# apache port 80 (nginx uses other ports)
EXPOSE 80

FROM base AS dev
RUN --mount=type=bind,target=localhost/htdocs,source=./src,rw
COPY apache-dev.conf /etc/apache2/conf.d/website.conf
CMD /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
```

docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  website:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      target: dev
    external_links:
      - mysql
    networks:
      - website-network

networks:
  website-network:
```

Comment: shows us your dockerfile.

Comment: Hi @RichardRublev, Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml file added. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After one week's struggling, I finally find a solution. Maybe it is not the best, maybe it is a dirty one, but it works for me. If anyone has a better solution, please post here and I won't mark this answer as the best answer for now.

**Short story**

We can just copy/paste a "working" `apr_dbd_mysql-1.so` file to alpine linux, `/usr/lib/apache2/apr_dbd_mysql.so`.

**Long story**

During the week, I tried upgrading Alpine to 3.15 and it didn't help. Then I found that I made some stupid things, for example, I want to connect MySQL server in another docker container, but I didn't install MySQL client in this container. And there is no need to add `LoadModule apr_dbd_mysql modules/apr_dbd_mysql.so` to `httpd.conf` at all!

But after I corrected the configurations, apache still gave me the same error. Then I found MySQL official document said `my_init()` function has been removed from MySQL 8, user has no need to call this function anymore. But I could not change `apr-util` package, no such knowledge, so how about install a previous version of MySQL client which still contains the  `my_init()` function?

I googled about it and in Alpine 3.7, the MySQL client is old enough to have this `my_init()` function. But when I installed it via docker, I got some network issues and could not finish the installation.

Finally, I went back to Ubuntu, because the website was transferred from there and I have installed **`libaprutil1-dbd-mysql`** package to enable MySQL driver. But soon I realised that there is no `libaprutil1-dbd-mysql` package in Alpine.

At the end, I found that the `apr_dbd_mysql-1.so` file size is just 4k. That may be just a header|interface file, no actual function implementation at all. If it works in ubuntu, that means `apr_dbd_mysql-1.so` file on Unbuntu may be generated without that `my_init()` function. Based on this guess, I tried and it works!

Hooray!